# Error while running sudo apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

I get this error when running `sudo apt-get update`. What's it mean?

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 94.5 kB in 8s (11.0kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
suresh@suresh-Lenovo-G50-70:~$
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTzuI.png)

Comment: Please, provide text outputs rather than screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [Tualatrix PPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTzuI.png) has not been updated for 16.04. You should remove it, as there are no packages for your system, so you won't be able to download anything. `apt-get` also sees it as a security issue since it hasn't been updated.

[Remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

and then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: This one is better. thnx :)